# Move the PDF/Markdown/Print Button to CV Edit/View Page

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I was recently trying to get a PDF version of my CV, but for the life of me I could not find a way other than print to PDF. I seemed to have recalled that there was a button somewhere, but ended up giving up on the search.

*My solution caused some other issues as my anti-virus decided to inject some HTML, so I needed to go about it in a "hacky" way (to get a clean print to PDF)*

...fast forward about 3 or 4 weeks, and I'm tinkering in the CV Settings page... lo and behold, in all its glory, there it is... hidden from plain sight, yet extremely useful.

[image]

**Request:**

Can we move these buttons to a location more obvious, as (to me) they don't seem related to Settings in any way or form.

> The page at "//stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv/edit/xxxxx" seems like a good fit